# AWS secret manager returned only master host from RDS cluster. Slave hosts are not returned

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-secrets-manager

I am creating a AWS lambda in python language to fetch data from RDS(Aurora).
RDS credentials are stored in AWS secret manager. While creating secret, I was asked to select RDS cluster. Selected RDS cluster has master as well as slave hosts.
But when I fetch credentials in lambda by accessing secret created using secret manager, it returns only master host and not slave hosts in that cluster.
Is there any way to access slave hosts?

Code:

```
def get_secret():
    secret_name = "abc"
    region_name = "xyz"

    session = boto3.session.Session()
    client = session.client(
        service_name='secretsmanager',
        region_name=region_name
    )
    try:
        get_secret_value_response = client.get_secret_value(
            SecretId=secret_name
        )
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e)
    else:
        if 'SecretString' in get_secret_value_response:
            secret = get_secret_value_response['SecretString']
            #Print Credentials
            print(secret)
```

Output:

```
{"username":"xxxxx","password":"yyyyyyy","engine":"mysql","host":"**returned only master host here**","port":1234,"dbClusterIdentifier":"aaaaaaaaa"}
```

Answer (score 3):

The password (the actual secret) will be the same on the master and slave. Since Secrets Manager only needs to know the master in order to complete rotation, that is all that it stores in the secret.

Normally, applications just connect to the master so they can write data. If you want to connect to the read only slave (for example to offload the master), you will probably have to call [describe db clusters](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/rds.html#RDS.Client.describe_db_clusters) to get the slave endpoint. However, this is not always a great idea. If a slave is put under a heavy load failures to sync with the master can occur leaving it in a broken state. I have seen this before with MySQL and it takes manual action to recover the slave.